# create single video form 3 separate videos using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I was trying to create single video form 3 separate videos using FFmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug  -i /home/ubuntu/test/1569317318/15693173181124138568.webm   -i /home/ubuntu/test/1569317318/1569317318867082351.webm   -i /home/ubuntu/test/1569317318/1569317318191333163.webm  -filter_complex '[0]scale=320:-1[a];[1]scale=320:-1[b];[2]scale=320:-1[c];[3]scale=320:-1[d];[a]pad=640:480[x];[x][b]overlay=320[y];[y][c]overlay=0:240[z];[z][d]overlay=320:240;[0][1]amix'  -c:v libx264   -crf 23   -preset veryfast   -shortest   /home/ubuntu/test/1569317318/1569317318478598265.mp4
```

This is not woking, It throws an error like bellow

> Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description
>   [0]scale=320:-1[a];[1]scale=320:-1[b];[2]scale=320:-1[c];[3]scale=320:-1[d];[a]pad=640:480[x];[x][b]overlay=320[y];[y][c]overlay=0:240[z];[z][d]overlay=320:240;[0][1]amix.

How to fix it? If we provide four inputs, It is working

Answer (score 1):

The filter `[3]scale=320:-1[d]` refers to the 4th input. Since there is no fourth input, remove it.

Since `[d]` is no longer created, remove the overlay as well: `[z][d]overlay=320:240`

So,

`ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -i /home/ubuntu/test/1569317318/15693173181124138568.webm   -i /home/ubuntu/test/1569317318/1569317318867082351.webm -i /home/ubuntu/test/1569317318/1569317318191333163.webm -filter_complex '[0]scale=320:-1[a];[1]scale=320:-1[b];[2]scale=320:-1[c];[a]pad=640:480[x];[x][b]overlay=320[y];[y][c]overlay=0:240;[0][1]amix' -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast -shortest   /home/ubuntu/test/1569317318/1569317318478598265.mp4`